# Issues with Tailwind Dynamic Class Values Compilation in React

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I'm currently facing issues while trying to create a grid based on a dynamically generated grid size variable in Tailwind CSS. When I use the variable to set grid-template-rows and grid-template-columns, the class names don't get compiled as expected. Instead, I'm getting class names with the generated values enclosed in square brackets.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```js
const App = () => {
  const gridSize = getGridSize();
  const players = getPlayers();
  // const numberOfPlayers = players.length;
  const activePlayer = getActivePlayer();

  const gridItems = Array(gridSize * gridSize)
    .fill(null)
    .map((_, index) => (
      <div
        key={index}
        className="bg-orange-300 rounded-lg w-16 h-16 cursor-pointer"
      ></div>
    ));

  return (
    <div
      className={`bg-[${players[activePlayer]}] w-[60vw] h-[100vh] mx-[20vw] flex justify-center items-center`}
    >
      <div className={`grid grid-rows-${gridSize} grid-cols-${gridSize} gap-2`}>
        {gridItems}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The problem is visible in the resulting class names with square brackets, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

In contrast, when static values are used, the class names are applied correctly, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Please help me understand why these dynamic class values with Tailwind CSS variables aren't getting compiled as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could look at using the `style` attribute instead like:

```
const App = () => {
  // …

  return (
    <div
      className="w-[60vw] h-[100vh] mx-[20vw] flex justify-center items-center"
      style={{ backgroundColor: players[activePlayer] }}
    >
      <div
        className="grid gap-2"
        style={{
          gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`,
          gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`,
        }}
      >
        {gridItems}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks al lot just an update for the grid part it'd be
style={{
          gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`,
          gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`,
        }}

Comment: Indeed, thank you, corrected.